# How to filter array of objects and check if more than one object inside the array has the same property value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5

How to filter the array of objects and check if more than one object inside the array has the same property value plan "enterprise" in Javascript.

```
    this.accounts
              .filter(
                item => item.plan === 'enterprise'
              )
              // then how can I check if there is more than one object
              // containing above enterprise value? if so then return some message.
          }
```

How above filtering can be continued for achieving the result?

Comment: .filter() method iterates over all the elements of an array .

Comment: you ve just checked it, it will accrue all the object which have the specified prop

Comment: @EugenSunic I need to check if there are more than one object with that filter then return some message

Comment: check the length of the returned array and if > 1 issue alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the length of the array and then check if it is greater than one, hence print a message

```
 const elmCount = this.accounts
   .filter(
     item => item.plan === 'enterprise'
   ).length

 if (elmCount > 1) {
   console.log('print message')
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

After you have perform the filter you can just count the number of items in the result of the `filter` method. which will tell you how many accounts with enterprise plan exists

```js
var accounts = [
 {id: 1, name: "Account 1", plan: "basic"},
 {id: 2, name: "Account 2", plan: "medium"},
 {id: 3, name: "Account 3", plan: "enterprise"},
 {id: 4, name: "Account 4", plan: "medium"},
 {id: 5, name: "Account 5", plan: "enterprise"}
]


var enterpriseAccounts = accounts.filter(item => item.plan === "enterprise");

if(enterpriseAccounts.length > 1 ) {
  console.log('There are more than one enterprise account');
} else {
 console.log('There are 0 or 1 enterprise account');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter and then get the length.

```js
accounts = [{plan: 'test'}, {plan: 'extra'}, {plan: 'enterprise'}, {plan: 'basic'}, {plan: 'enterprise'}];
let length = accounts.filter(item => item.plan === 'enterprise').length;

if (length>1) console.log('enterprise more than once: ' + length);
```